# How can we test the fromDate and toDate in integration testing. following are the code for the Date

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-integration-test

How to test the last and current 3 month date in the flutter.
Is anyone having the solution for that.

```
    RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(children: [
                          TextSpan(
                              text: DateTimeHelper.getFormattedDateTime(fromDate,
                                  dateFormat: DateTimeHelper.dateOnlyText),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                          TextSpan(text: " to "),
                          TextSpan(
                              text: DateTimeHelper.getFormattedDateTime(toDate,
                                  dateFormat: DateTimeHelper.dateOnlyText),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                        ]),
                      ),
```

Comment: Kindly detail your question? What kind of test?

Comment: Use a variable for the button text, and then update the variable and call setState, the button text will change.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two dates:

```
var today = DateTime.now();
var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(some_date); // Suppose your stored date is in Milliseconds Epoch format.
bool isSame = date.day == today.day;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can add to the previous answer that it is possible to assign a key to some widget and use the key to get the value from it.
Smth like this

`await driver.tap(find.text(lifeStyle)`